# What is the difference between message size and request size for AWS MSK?

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

Reading over the [MSK Quota documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/limits.html), I see there are two values

```
Maximum message size 8 MB

Maximum request size 100 MB
```

Is the message size for individual messages and the request size for a batch request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Kafka producer clients batch requests, rather than send one record at a time.

A batch contains many messages, each of a certain size.

A request size is the total of all messages, plus extra metadata.

"Request" size may also include other Kafka network interactions, however the ProduceBatch should be the largest.